# TFS Database Edition doesn't seem to Script Logins

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, tfs, database-project

I'm trying to put all our databases in TFS.  For this purpose we're using TFS Database edition - I've seen some of the other Dev teams use it and it seems pretty good.

Problem is that it doesn't seem to script the logins - the users are linked to logins which now break due to the logins not being scripted.

As far as I can tell I can't get around this - the Schemas need the users which in turn need the logins.

How do you handle logins in TFS Database Projects?

This is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with the database projects much but I think the way you handle this is using the server project and adding them there.

[This MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483214.aspx#id0100034) talks about some of the new features in GDR which include server projects.

Here is a link to the faq http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819149.aspx on msdn that talks about server projects a bit as well.

Comment: But what's the point of having non-server projects then?  Since you would never be able to create a project that compiles??

Comment: They set up the projects to represent the way SQL Server is set up. If you have a solution, you'll have a project for each database and a project for what's shared between each database at the server level.

Comment: Thanks, this stuff is rather confusing to me